# Placing the same Div's one behind the other?

Tags: html, css, performance

I want to set several div's in succession, but find it unnecessary to copy the code again and again. How it is possible for me to put 5 times the same div's behind the other in a more effective way than I've described here?

HTML:

```
<div class="procduct">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/>                
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="procduct">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/>                
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="procduct">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/>                
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="procduct">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/>                
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.procduct {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    float: left;
}
    .image {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
    .overlay {
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-left: 17px;
    display:none;
}
    .procduct:hover .overlay {
    display:block; 

}
    .procduct:hover .image {
    opacity:0.00;    
}
    .clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghac101/hvpn4/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way with vanilla HTML production to magically reduce the work required. You can, however, use a framework like [HAML](http://haml.info/) to reduce some of the repetitiveness.

For example, the code:

```
<div class='content'>Hello, World!</div>
```

in HAML, can become:

```
.content Hello, World!
```

It's not exactly what you're looking for, per se, but it is probably as close as you'll get. The bottom line is you can't cut corners with writing HTML this way. You could use another language like JavaScript or PHP to create or duplicate HTML elements as you need them, however.

Answer (score 0):

There sure is:

```
<?php

$numberofdivs = 5;

for ($i=1;$i<$numberofdivs;$i++) {
  echo '<div class="procduct">
        <div class="image">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>';
}

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a good idea, but the problem is, that the code is 5 times the same in this document.
Do you think there is a possibility to post this code one time and add the content to css file or something like that, so that the code only appears one time?

Comment: What this code does, is just pasting 5x the same code, if this is not what you want, what are you searching for?

Comment: @user3817660 If you only want the code to appear once, why write it five times?

Comment: I want to compress that code.
Same function but only writing 
<div class="procduct">
        <div class="image">
        <img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>'
one time, you know what i mean?

Comment: @user3817660 So you *dont* want it to appear once. You want it to appear multiple times.

Comment: Yes, the objects should be there multiple times, but the code should be as short as possible.
And if possible no repetions.

Comment: Well, if you are just asking if the code you just have written could be written shorter, I think it can't. You can strip the image class, and then use the image tag to style it. Although this doesn't help much, and with some style functions it doesn't work as well. What you have written now can't be written with less code, I think.